# Implementing array of structures( similar to C) in python by reading data from a file

Tags: python

i want to implement the following in python,
in C, it is like below, there is a structure

```
struct xyz {
char name[50];
char type[50];
char link[50];
char level[50];
}XYZ;
```

And i have created an array of this struct xyz as following:

```
XYZ array[] = 
{ {"Mac", "char", "list","one"},
  {"John", "char", "list","three"},
  ...
  ...
};
```

and accessing these by array[0], array[1] etc.
In python script, suppose i have listed these array elements in a text file like below, e.g. file.txt

```
Mac, char, list, one
John, char, list, three
...
...
```

Now i have to read the file.txt, and store them into my python script similar to array of structs and access accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is a bit off.

This will create an array of arrays of 4 values:

```
XYZ = [ 
    ["Mac", "char", "list","one"],
    ["John", "char", "list","three"],
    ...
    ...
]
```

This will create an array of objects with 4 fields:

```
XYZ = [ 
    {"name": "Mac", "type": "char", "link": "list", "level": "one"},
    {"name": "John", "type": "char", "link": "list", "level": "three"},
    ...
    ...
]
```

To read this data from file into structure like #2:

```
import csv

XYZ = []
with open("data.csv") as csv_data:
    entries = csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter=",")
    # This can be done with list comprehension, but will be difficult to read
    for entry in entries:
        XYZ.append({
            "name": entry[0],
            "type": entry[1],
            "link": entry[2],
            "level": entry[3]
        })
```

Comment: His syntax is C, not Python, which is why it looks so odd as Python. :D

Comment: thanks a lot,it is similar to what i was trying to do but how would i get the corresponding value? meaning if i search the string 'Mac' in XYZ, and if found then i need the corresponding type, link and level at the same time..

Comment: if you need to search for "name=Mac":
`[entry for entry in XYZ if entry.name == "Mac"]` will return you the list of corresponding entries.

Comment: Please don't mind, i am a beginner i python`[entry for entry in XYZ if entry.name == "Mac"]`
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: working but i am not getting the right values, it prints the values of last index e.g. char,
John,
list,
three

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32821/discussion-between-mishik-and-jaiswal)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   lines = list(reader)

print(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of what was suggested here, you might want to take advantage of the fact that Python can do OOP (as opposed to C), so adding to Burjan's answer, I would do something like:

```
class xyz():
def __init__(self, name, type):
    self.name = name
    self.type = type
    // etc
```

And then call something like `result = [ xyz(*line) for line in lines ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

from collections import namedtuple
XYZ = namedtuple('xyz', ['name', 'type', 'link', 'level'])

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
   lines = [XYZ(*line) for line in reader]

for item in lines:
    print(item.name)
    print(item.type)
    #etc.
```

Comment: thanks, i tried it but getting error: `lines = [XYZ(line) for line in reader]` `TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 5 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: @Jaiswal, that should be `lines = [XYZ(*line) for line in reader]`